# Display and Save the Selective Text of Edittext in Bold, italic and underline and send to server as edited in android

Tags: android

I want to make a text editing toolbar for the editText in which I can apply alignment, style, and list to selected text. And this edited text should be uploaded to the server in the form which is edited and not in normal form.

I have tried the applying style but it is only applicable for displaying and when I check in "Log.e" I get a normal string.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,         savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
rootView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personal_report,container,false)
  getActivity()!!.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

init()
return rootView
}

fun init(){
     selectionStart = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionStart()
     selectionEnd = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionEnd()

  imgBoldEditText = rootView!!.findViewById(R.id.imgBoldEditText)
  imgItalicEditText = rootView!!.findViewById(R.id.imgItalicEditText)

  imgBoldEditText.setOnClickListener(this)
  imgItalicEditText.setOnClickListener(this)

    styleBold = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
    styleNormal = StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL)
    styleItalc = StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC)
    underLine = UnderlineSpan()

    }


override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if(v== imgBoldEditText){

        val wholeText = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getText().toString()
        val start = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionStart()
        val end = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionEnd()
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(wholeText)
        sb.setSpan(styleBold, start, end,  0)
        rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.setText(sb)

    }
    if(v == imgItalicEditText){
        val wholeText = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getText().toString()
        val start = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionStart()
        val end = rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.getSelectionEnd()
        val sb = SpannableStringBuilder(wholeText)
        sb.setSpan(styleItalc, start, end, 0)
       rootView!!.personalReport_edtContent.setText(sb)
        Log.e("finalText",Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()).toString())

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upbzO.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you style a text using spannables, it does not create HTML tags. Spannables work internally with the `TextView`. What you could do is - add HTML tags manually.

Instead of,

```
Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()).toString()
```

you could use,

```
"<i>${sb.toString()}<\i>"
```

You have 2 options:

1. Use HTML encoding and tags to save and display the text.
2. Use an internal schema (you can decide), eg. Markdown => `_italic text_`. Save your text in that format and when you want to display it, create spannables based on regex to detect the style.

You can also use existing solutions such as [Markwon](https://github.com/noties/Markwon)